# How do I use '#attached' to attach a style sheet?

Tags: 7, theming

I know that `drupal_add_css` is depreciated, and that we should use `#attached` instead to attach a css style sheet to a module.

I am trying to replace the following (which works):

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/mymodule.css');
```

with `#attached`.  But haven't found exactly where and how to add it.

Here is my second attempt (it still does not work):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view()
 */
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
  if ('mymodule' == $delta) {
    $render = array();
    $list = mymodule_fetch_from_info();
    foreach ($list as $element) {
      $render[] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => $element[0],
        '#weight' => $element[1],
      );
    }
    $blocks['subject'] = t('Mymodule');
    $blocks['content'] = $render;
    $blocks['#attached'] = array (
      'css' => array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.css',
       ),
    );
    return $blocks;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use #attached inside your hook_theme implementation. Instead, you should add it when you're building a render array:

```
$blocks['content'] = $render;
$blocks['content']['#attached'] = array (
  'css' => array(
    drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.css',
  ),
);
```

As kiamlaluno already pointed out in the comments, in your code example `$blocks['content']` is the render array, so the `#attached` element must be part of that array.

Comment: `$blocks` is not a render array, but `$blocks['content']` is.